# VBA (Excel 2007) - How can | override default shortcut behaviour with Onkey

Tags: excel, vba, keyboard, excel-2007, shortcut

Excel 2007, different from Excel 2003, uses hotkeys like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> like shortcuts to specific features.

So if I use in a VBA module

```
         Application.OnKey("%C","ProcAltC")
```

It doesn't work. In other words, pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> doesn't call "ProcAltC" routine.

How can I override that default shortcut behavior in order to use `OnKey` successfully?

Comment: Paulo, first of all do you actually mean to say Ctrl+ instead of Al+?

Comment: It's Alt combination keys and not Ctrl. Almost any Ctrl keys combinations can be redirected normally using OnKey, at the same way than Excel 2003. I have a huge addin written in Excel 2003, that uses tenths of shortcuts, including some Alt keys.

Answer (score 1):

In Office 2010 I can produce an action on <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> by...

```
    Sub Test01()
     With Application
'[lower case c, s, v]:
      .OnKey "%c", "Proc01"
      .OnKey "%s", "Proc02"
      .OnKey "%v", "Proc03"
     End With
    End Sub

    Sub Proc01()
     MsgBox "C"
    End Sub

    Sub Proc02()
     MsgBox "S"
    End Sub

    Sub Proc03()
     MsgBox "V"
    End Sub
```

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> is a different story.  If you absolutely must use combinations like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, you're going to have to compile and employ an OS system hook.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't have Office 2010, so I cannot verify. My last version is 2007. Googling I've learned that I can disable keys combination using Microsoft Resource Kit, but Excel remains sending warnings.

Comment: Well I have 2007 but haven't installed it on the machine I work with now, and don't really have any intention of doing so since the VBE in it was buggy.  Writing a system hook is available to you. It's a DLL that you would call from VBA code. It would intercept any keystroke combos you specify and respond with a function call of your choosing.